# Firebase Web Login on domain hosted by hosting company?

Tags: firebase-authentication, hosted

I have setup a Firebase Web Login with Email/Password sign in locally on my computer. I want to implement it on my domain, which is hosted by a web hosting company, so my domain and all it's catalogues are password protected.

Is this possible? Where/how do I configure this?

I have supplied my current setup as a snippet.

```js
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
if (user) {
    // User is signed in.

    document.getElementById('signed-in').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('sign-in').style.display = "none";
} else {
    // No user is signed in.

    document.getElementById('signed-in').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('sign-in').style.display = "initial";}
});

const form = document.getElementById("sign-in-form");
form.addEventListener("submit", login);

function login(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    let email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    let password = document.getElementById("password").value;

    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
        // Handle Errors here.
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        
        document.getElementById('error-message').textContent = errorMessage;
        document.getElementById('error-message-div').style.display = "block";
        
      });
}
```

```css
body, html {
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
    color: #999;
}

a {
    color: #57b846;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    color: black;
  }

#wrapper {
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 500px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 20px 0px; #000;
}

#sign-in-header {
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #57b846;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 0 0;
}

#sign-in-body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 50px 50px 0 50px;
}

input {
    outline: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #1b3815;
    line-height: 1.2;
    width: 100%;
    height: 55px;
    background: #ebebeb;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 25px;
    padding: 0 35px 0 35px;
}

#email {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

input[type=submit] {
    color: white;
    background-color: #57b846;
    padding: 0 35px 0 35px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {

    background-color: #2e7522;
}

#forgot-password {
    text-align: right;
}

#signed-in {
    display: none;
}

#error-message-div {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #D8000C;
    width: 100%;
    background: #FFBABA ;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

#error-message-div {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Login - The Meadow</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:400,600,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <section>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="sign-in">
                <div id="sign-in-header">
                    <h1>Sign In</h1>
                </div>
                <div id="sign-in-body">
                    <form id="sign-in-form">
                        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail"><br>
                        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"><br><br>
                        <div id="forgot-password">Forgot <a href="#">Username / Password?</a></div>
                        <input type="submit" value="SIGN IN">
                    </form>
                    <div id="error-message-div"><strong><span id="error-message"></span></strong></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="signed-in">You are signed in</div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.9.1/firebase-app.js"></script>

    <!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
        https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.9.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.9.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.9.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>

    <script>
    // Your web app's Firebase configuration
    var firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "AIzaSyBHoY2Vjhw6fbI6abd_osRzbkfgAZA5yt4",
        authDomain: "fir-web-login-3b6c2.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://fir-web-login-3b6c2.firebaseio.com",
        projectId: "fir-web-login-3b6c2",
        storageBucket: "fir-web-login-3b6c2.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "569718654639",
        appId: "1:569718654639:web:51b3518dc6a0096c58765a",
        measurementId: "G-G034W12YF0"
    };
    // Initialize Firebase
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    firebase.analytics();
    </script>
    
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the problem?  Please edit the question to be clear where you're stuck.

Comment: @DougStevenson I have supplied my code now. I just don't know how to go about implementing it on my domain. I guess I somehow need to tell Firebase to direct unauthenticated visitors of my pages to the login page. After login, the user should be taken to the initially requested page. Where do I set this up?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Authentication can be used on any hosting provider.

It can also be used with any custom domain, no matter where you registered that domain. Just be sure to add the custom domain to the list of <kbd>Authorized domains</kbd> in the [Firebase Authentication console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/authentication/providers).

Comment: Thanks! Is adding my domain to the list of authorized domains automatically going to make it and all it's catalogues password protected?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Can you clarify a bit what you expect Firebase to do there?

Comment: Unauthenticated visitors of my pages (like mydomain.com/catalogue1/page.html or mydomain.com/anothercatalogue/secrets.html) should directed to the login page. After successfull login, the visitor should be taken to the initially requested page. Where and how do I set this up?

Comment: Making subpages check whether a user is authenticated is unrelated to configuring a custom domain, nor does it depend on where the site is hosted. For details on how to check if the user is authenticated, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user

Comment: I know how to check if the user is authenticated, I'm already doing it in my code. Is there a way to make Firebase password protect my whole domain, or do I have apply this logic to all my subpages?

Comment: Files hosted in Firebase Hosting are publicly readable. There is no way to password protect those files. Other hosting providers may allow you to configure certain requirements before a user can access specific files.